# ftp mkdir permission

Tags: permissions, ftp, file-permissions

I can create a folder on a pc that I connect to via ftp.

When I create a folder using mkdir

and then to move some files using "rename" I get access is denied.

Is there a way around this? I'm doing this programatically and creating a backup folder for each day.

I created a folder called archive via FTP and gave the FTP user full permission on the folder. When I create any subfolders via FTP I noticed the ftp user still has full permissions but I still appear to be getting the error message.

See below:

```
rename Order957842.xml archive/03102010/Order957842.xml
350 File exists, ready for destination name
550 archive/03102010/Order957842.xml: Access is denied.
```

Any ideas how to get around this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is to do with the ftp root folder being set up as something other than c:\inetpub\ftproot. I now change the directory to this one(ftproot) and do all necessary tasks. Ftp doesn;t appear to have natural permisssions in other folders apart from this one.